# Showing up an ExcelSheet in Java Standard Application

Tags: java, excel, plugins

I am developing Java application to send some details to Server. I need to show the excel sheet inside my application. I want to Know there is any jar files (or) plugin available in Java to show the excel sheet inside the application. Is this possible means share the jar files and plugin names? Also, I need to know whether, it will slow up our other process of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Apache POI in the past which is an open source free project to manipulate data in Excel.  You can download the latest stable release from [here](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.9) which should give you several jars.

```
poi-3.9-20121203
poi-examples-3.9-20121203
poi-excelant-3.9-20121203
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203
poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203
```

You would also need these, even though they are not included they are 3rd party dependancies, and required for parts of POI to function

```
dom4j-1.7-20060614
xmlbeans-2.4.0
```

As far as opening a spreadsheet within an application goes I don't know whether this is possible, but the [cookbook](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) on the Apache website has an extensive list of examples to get you started.

Good Luck!

Edit:
With regards to opening the spreadsheet up in the application, Java Desktop can be helpful for this sort of thing.  Something like the below may help.

```
    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
    try {
        //Desktop.getDesktop().edit(new File("D:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx"));
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
} else {
    System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache POI(http://poi.apache.org/) or JExcel(http://www.teamdev.com/jexcel/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for reading / writing excel file.

Here are good tutorials to start:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/